# Erro na função fgets()

Tags: c, gerenciamento-de-memória, alocação

O programa dá *segmentation fault* (*core dump*) ao executar a função `fgets()`. Alguma ideia?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp=NULL;
    char *f_name;

    switch(argc)
        {
        case(1):fgets(f_name,100,stdin);break;  
        case(2):f_name=argv[1];break;   
        default:printf("\nErro de syntax %s", argv[0]); exit(0);
        }

fputs(f_name, stdout);

fp=fopen(f_name, "r");

if (fp==NULL)
printf("\nNão abriu.\n");
else 
printf("\nAbriu\n");

}
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 7):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char f_name[100];

    switch(argc) {
        case(1): fgets(f_name, 100, stdin); break;  
        case(2): strncpy(f_name, argv[1], 100); break;   
        default: printf("\nErro de syntax %s", argv[0]); exit(0);
    }

    fputs(f_name, stdout);
    fp = fopen(f_name, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        printf("\nNão abriu.\n");
    else 
        printf("\nAbriu\n");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/FgetsProblem.c).

Isto alocará a memória necessária para guardar o [conteúdo lido em `stdin`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42981/101) com o [`fgets()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets). Neste caso a declaração como *array* garante a alocação prévia da memória no *stack*.

Também é possível manter o uso com ponteiro e dando um [`malloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) após a declaração e antes do `fgets()`, mas acho que para você vai ser mais fácil usar a forma de *array*, já que usou antes.

Existem outros erros no código agora foram sanados no exemplo acima. O principal é que no segundo `case` estava copiando o conteúdo errado, usando a função [`strncpy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) você copia byte a byte o conteúdo do primeiro argumento passado ao programa.

Não diretamente relacionado ao problema, mas para entender melhor sobre o gerenciamento de memória, veja [O que são e onde estão a "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

Answer (score 3):

Você tem um problema aqui entre o uso de *arrays* e ponteiros.

```
char *f_name;
```

Aqui declarou um ponteiro sem valor definido. Quando faz:

```
fgets(f_name, 100, stdin);
```

O `fgets()` espera receber no primeiro argumento um ponteiro apontando para alguma memória com ao menos `100` bytes. O primeiro é o ponteiro para o seu *buffer* e o segundo é o tamanho do mesmo. Quando você passou um ponteiro não inicializado, está fazendo o `fgets()` escrever em algum lugar qualquer desconhecido da memória, causando o seu **crash**.

A solução, como o Maniero falou, é criar uma *array* com `100` *chars* logo no começo, assim:

```
char f_name[100];
```

Quando faz:

```
fgets(f_name, 100, stdin);
```

Está agora passando um ponteiro para o primeiro elemento da *array* (escrever `f_name` nesse caso é equivalente a `&f_name[0]`). Você efetivamente passou um ponteiro para um *buffer* de `100` bytes, tudo vai funcionar. Exceto...

```
f_name = argv[1];
```

Aqui `f_name` é uma *array*, e setar o valor de *arrays* é ilegal. Isso nem faz muito sentido. O que você quer na verdade é copiar os dados que estão em `argv[1]` para a *array*. Para isso use o [`strncpy`](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy), assim:

```
strncpy(f_name, argv[1], 100);
```

A função vai fazer a cópia de até `100` bytes da origem para o destino.

Comment: Como eu comentei na outra resposta, strncpy não é tão segura quanto parece, pois não necessariamente finaliza a string resultante com '\0'. Soluções? Dá pra usar snprintf, strncat, ou strncpy seguido de `f_name[99] = '\0'`.

Answer (score 3):

Como eu já estava escrevendo comentários um pouco complexos nas outras respostas, resolvi adicionar a minha.

Estou usando 2 variáveis separadas, uma para guardar caracteres e outra para apontar para o array desejado (f_buffer ou argv[1]).

O código abaixo não está testado, e deve estar faltando no mínimo uma coisa: remover o '\n' que o fgets deixa no final do array, logo antes do '\0' (o '\n' representa o Enter que o usuário digitou). Outras funções removem o '\n', mas o fgets não, permitindo diferenciar uma entrada truncada de uma entrada completa. Fazer esse tratamento fica como "exercício para o leitor" (como eu odiava quando eu lia isso num livro, hahahaha...). Mudei os printf's no final para indicar melhor o que o programa está fazendo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 100

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char *f_name, f_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    switch(argc) {
        case 1:
            fgets(f_buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
            /* A FAZER: remover o '\n' do fim do do nome. */
            f_name = f_buffer;
            break;
        case 2:
            f_name = argv[1];
            break;
        default:
            printf("\nErro de syntax %s", argv[0]);
            exit(0);
    }

    fputs(f_name, stdout);

    fp = fopen(f_name, "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
        printf("\nNão abriu [[%s]].\n", f_name);
    else 
        printf("\nAbriu [[%s]]\n", f_name);
}
```