# Descobrir string dentro de string sem biblioteca string.h?

Tags: c, string

Minha função precisa verificar se uma string está contida em outra e falar onde ocorreu o primeiro local onde a letra ficou igual, mas está retornando sempre o tamanho da primeira string

O que tem de errado na minha implementação?

meu codigo:

```
void str_conteudo( char str1[], char str2[])
{  
int i=0;
int y;

while(str1[i] != str2[i] )
{
    if (str2[i] != str1[i])
    {
        y=i;
    }
    i++;

}

if(y>0)
printf("Indice do primeiro caractere que contem a string 2: %d ", y);
else
printf("A string 2 nao esta contida na string 1. \n");

}
```

Comment: O problema que você está tentando resolver se chama `substring`. Procurar por algoritmos de busca de substrings e entendê-los a fundo vai te ajudar bastante

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na sua implementação tem a lógica que percorre as letras da frase principal, mas ficou a faltar a lógica que vê se cada letra é igual as letras da segunda string.

Tentando aproveitar o máximo da sua lógica pode fazer assim:

```
void str_conteudo( char str1[], char str2[]) {
    int i=0,j, k;
    int y = -1; //y começa a -1, pois estava sem valor de inicio

    while(str1[i] != '\0') { // enquanto a string principal não termina
        if (str2[0] == str1[i]) { //se a letra em que vai é igual à 1a letra da substring
            //percorrer enquanto ambas as letras são iguais e até ao fim da substring
            for (j=i+1, k=1; str1[j]!='\0' && str2[k]!='\0' && str1[j] == str2[k];++j,k++);

            if (str2[k] == '\0'){ //se a segunda foi até ao fim então achou
                y = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }

    if(y>=0) // >= 0 e não > 0
        printf("Indice do primeiro caractere que contem a string 2: %d \n", y);
    else
        printf("A string 2 nao esta contida na string 1. \n");
}
```

Testes

```
str_conteudo ("Frase de teste","de"); //6 
str_conteudo ("Frase de teste","teste"); //9
str_conteudo ("Frase de teste","Frase"); //0
str_conteudo ("Frase de teste","cuFra"); // não contem
str_conteudo ("Frase de teste","testem"); // não contem
```

[Veja estes testes no Ideone](https://ideone.com/mBZCKv)

A maior diferença para o código que tinha está no que foi adicionado dentro do `if` no `while`.

Nunca é boa ideia este tipo de funções escreverem ou lerem conteudo. Devem apenas retornar o resultado, dando liberdade a quem chama de fazer o que quiser com esse resultado. Para alem disto o próprio `if` que tem no `while` nem seria necessário se alterasse mais algumas coisas.

Pegando nestes pontos que mencionei eu trocava a função para algo como:

```
int str_conteudo( char str1[], char str2[]) {
    int i=0, j, k;
    for(i = 0; str1[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        for (j = i,k = 0;str1[j]!= '\0' && str2[k] != '\0' && str1[j] == str2[k]; ++j,k++);
        if (str2[k] == '\0'){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Naturalmente que podia ter trocado a iteração e acesso para sintaxe de ponteiros que ficaria mais curto, mas optei por manter com índice para tornar a solução comparável e parecida com a sua.

Agora os testes tem que passar a mostrar o valor obtido pela função, que devolve `-1` sempre que não achar a substring:

```
printf("%d\n", str_conteudo ("Frase de teste","de")); //6
printf("%d\n", str_conteudo ("Frase de teste","teste")); //9
printf("%d\n", str_conteudo ("Frase de teste","Frase")); //0
printf("%d\n", str_conteudo ("Frase de teste","cuFra")); //-1
printf("%d\n", str_conteudo ("Frase de teste","testem")); //-1
```

[Veja estes testes também no Ideone](https://ideone.com/TS1tkp)

Apenas para referência, deixo o mesmo exemplo de cima implementado com notação de ponteiros, ainda que exatamente a mesma solução:

```
int str_conteudo( char *str1, char *str2) {
    char *curr1 = str1, *s1, *s2;
    while(*curr1){
        for(s1 = curr1, s2 = str2; *s1 && *s2 && *s1 == *s2; ++s1, ++s2);
        if (!*s2) return curr1 - str1;
        curr1++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Como nota final, a lógica que está a implementar é a que a função nativa [`strstr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/) fornece.

Comment: Não vou fazer uma agora, mas se fosse exemplificar, faria um loop e dentro uma state machine. Um ponteiro na agulha, outro no palheiro, e avançaria conforme o estado (procurando, comparando, resetando)

Comment: @Bacco E voltar depois com o ponteiro atrás caso não encontre um *full match* ?

Comment: sim, ainda assim seria mais otimizado nos casos que não encontrasse parcial ou que encontrasse inteiro - os unicos casos de rewind seriam parcial incompleto - Se quiser chamar de 2 loops, seriam "2 loops ocasionais" :)

Comment: @Bacco Tecnicamente seria um loop, apesar de que feito manualmente :D. Mas sim não seriam 2 loops escritos em forma de `for`/`while`. É certamente uma ideia interessante. Vou refrasear para não ferir suscetibilidades! :p

Comment: Lembrando que tou falando como exercício. Na prática eu acho que não implementaria isso pra uso real kkk. Aliás, eu vi um muito legal de busca otimizada de multiplas strings numa passada só, esse sim eu quero entender e fazer pra uso real.

Comment: @Isac essa alternativa da sua resposta é a implementação _naïve_, com tempo `O(|str1| * |str2|)`; dá para otimizar para `O( (|str1| - |str2|) * |str2|)`. Ou seja, essa alternativa vai ser sempre quadrática. Já a ideia do Bacco é `O(|str1| + |str2|)`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado não esqueça do rewind no caso da minha, se não for feito corretamente ele vai perder uma substring em algumas situações. (tinha exemplificado errado aqui)

Comment: Parece-me que a complexidade é igual, pois no segundo exemplo que eu tenho para nenhuma letra igual a minha solução é O(|str1|) que seria igual ao exemplo do Bacco. Porque deixar o ponteiro avançar e depois andar com ele para trás é basicamente o inner `for` que eu tenho mas escrito de outra forma. A menos que eu não esteja a visualizar a solução dele a 100%. Para todos os efeitos, em grande parte dos casos o meu *inner* `for` funciona como um `if`.

Comment: @Bacco o KMP que usa um FSA não precisa de um _rewind_ ao andar na `str1`/string grande que pode conter `str2`. Ele resolve em uma passada, e montar esse autômato baseado na `str2` eu acho que é linear.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado fico pensando que pra achar "ababac" dentro de "xxxxabababacxxx" sem rewind não dá certo, dá? Pq está contido, mas na primeira passada vai confundir os 5 primeiros caracteres depois dos x.

Comment: @Bacco dá sim, e quando eu era atleta da programação eu fazia em uma passada. Deixa eu estudar e postarei a resposta aqui, porque não lembro mais como é xD

Comment: Vou ver só mais tarde, pq agora realmente preciso dormir. Quero fazer uma de multiplas strings e alta performance, pq é pra substituir um LIKE no SQLite numa aplicação minha.

Comment: Se tiverem essas soluções depois postem para partilhar conhecimento! Que eu fiquei curioso.