# Como otimizar esse código (Time Limit Exceeded)?

Tags: c++

Esse código é uma possível solução do problema 1211 no URI Online Judge. No meu pc roda normal para os casos de teste, mas na plataforma eu recebo a mensagem de Time Limit Exceeded. Alguma idéia de otimização?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

struct telefone{
    char digito[200];
};

int main(void){

    long int i = 0, N = 0;
    int soma = 0, j = 0;

        cin >> N;

    while(N!= EOF){
    struct telefone tel[N];

    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        cin >> tel[i].digito;
    }
    int tamanho = strlen(tel[0].digito);

    for(i = 0; i < N - 1 ; i++){
        for(j=0; j<tamanho; j++){
                if (tel[i].digito[j] == tel[i+1].digito[j])
                    soma++;
                else break;
            }
    }
    cout << soma << endl;
    soma = 0;
    cin >> N;

    }
}
```

Comment: C não é C++, seu código é C++ e não C, editei as tags.

Comment: Eu não sei que problema é esse, o 1211 do URI judge. Se você puder sumarizá-lo para que nós possamos ter uma ideia melhor do que se trata, fica melhor tentar ajudar. Mas, se te ajudar, por esse vetor de escopo automático de tamanho `N` para ser alocado no começo do bloco a cada repetição, isso é um erro em programação competitiva. Melhor deixar esse vetor já alocado com seu valor máximo ou então nem usá-lo, se não for necessário guardar mais do que duas sequências de dígitos por vez

Comment: Exemplo de questão de programação competitiva que se encaixa bem melhor no formato do SOpt: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/306086/64969

Answer (score 1):

Use `while (!cin.eof())` no lugar de `while(N!= EOF)`.

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/mkugRS)