# Como alocar em memória contígua de uma estrutura que contém um vetor com tamanho definido pelo usuário?

Tags: c, array, struct, memória, alocação

Estava eu pensando em como responder [esta questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/373417/64969) e cheguei à conclusão que precisaria de uma estrutura de dados com:

- o tamanho de um conjunto
- um vetor de tamanho informado anteriormente

Seria algo assim a estrutura:

```
struct conjunto {
  int tamanho;
  int *conteudo;
};
```

Na minha primeira e ingênua ideia, eu alocariam uma região de memória para a estrutura e depois outra para o seu conteúdo:

```
struct conjunto* aloca_conjunto(int n) {
  struct conjunto *set = malloc(sizeof(struct conjunto));
  set.conteudo = n? malloc(sizeof(int)*n): NULL;
  set.tamanho = n;

  return set;
}
```

Porém, essa dupla alocação me incomoda por dois motivos:

1. fragmentação de memória
2. possível perda da [localidade de referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354265/64969)

Então, minha dúvida principal é

- Qual seria a alternativa para implementar em uma única alocação?

> Eu sei que mesmo que, hipoteticamente, eu conseguisse fazer essa alocação única, acessar o elemento da `n`-ésima posição do conjunto envolveria dois desreferenciamentos: `set->conteudo[n]`, mas pelo menos o ponteiro `set->conteudo` estaria próximo da região de memória desejada, maximizando a chance de um *cache hit* devido à localidade espacial.

Um ponto de curiosidade extra, para aprofundamento da questão:

- E se eu fosse colocar diversos elementos desses em uma região contígua de memória (no lugar de um vetor com os ponteiros), como faria para resgatar o `n`-ésimo elemento do tipo `struct conjunto` dessa região de memória?

Comment: Se você sabe quantos elementos o conteudo deve ter no momento em que aloca o conjunto consegue fazer tudo de uma vez jogando um pouco com a memoria. Para um conjunto com 5 inteiros faria assim: `conjunto = malloc(sizeof(int) * (5 + 1)); conjunto->conteudo = (&conjunto->tamanho) + 1;` o que assume que o layout da memoria para a estrutura coloca o inteiro antes do ponteiro, e sem qualquer padding

Comment: @Isac eu pensei em algo assim, porém tenho a impressão que `conjunto->tamanho` e `conjunto->tamanho[0]` compartilham bytes, então uma alteração em `conjunto->tamanho[0]` faria `conjunto->tamanho` apontar pra outro ponto. Então evoluí meu pensamento para `conjunto->conteudo = conjunto +1`, que apontaria para a posição logo depois de `[tamanho][*conteudo][bytes do vetor de conteudo]`. E, sim, nesse caso é possível afirmar que criarei o objeto com um tamanho conhecido. De toda sorte, realocações são possíveis também.

Comment: @Isac , tentei explicitar o ponto que acho mais importante (que se refere ao seu comentário) daquele que é uma curiosidade adicional

Comment: @Isac agora que você mencionou "solução criativa", pensei em criar um vetor de índices para fazer um aceso menos indireto, e esse vetor de índices precederia a região de memória com as estruturas, mas estou sem um compilador C para validar isso. Meu pensamento original foi exatamente esse que você comentou

Comment: É, eu repensei um pouco a minha ultima afirmação, pois embora seja verdade e dê para percorrer um vetor destes elementos, a criação do array tem de ser feita de forma meio artística, pois a estrutura para os tipos normais resulta em 8 bytes, mas cada elemento teria mais tamanho contíguo em memoria, logo a alocação não podia ser direta, e o mesmo para colocar lá os elementos. No final, acho que não compensa as maluqueiras que são necessárias fazer, para fugir a algumas alocações :D

Comment: @Isac , já tem uma resposta? Vou explorar essa questão durante o feriado

Comment: Achei que a minha resposta não seria particularmente interessante e optei por não a colocar. Mas daria para fazer construindo com o `realloc` do inicio para o fim e realocando sempre para o dobro, mas continuo a achar que o que se ganha em menos alocações perde-se em tempo de acesso, pois num vetor deste gênero não dará para aceder diretamente a um elemento sem percorrer os anteriores, uma vez que cada um tem tamanho diferente. Por esse motivo o local onde está o enésimo elemento na memoria continua não é determinístico e requer O(N) para aceder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É bem simples de fazer se estiver usando um compilador conforme pelo menos com o padrão C99, o que na prática quase qualquer situação. Use um VLA (Variable Array Length). Só tem que tomar o cuidado para alocar memória para a estrutura e os dados juntos. Acredito que isto atende os requisitos da pergunta.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    size_t tamanho;
    int conteudo[];
} Conjunto;

int main(void) {
    Conjunto *dados = malloc(sizeof(Conjunto) + 10 * sizeof(int));
    dados->tamanho = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < dados->tamanho; i++) dados->conteudo[i] = i;
    for (int i = 0; i < dados->tamanho; i++) printf("%d, ", dados->conteudo[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ocqc5I). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/VLA). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/Vla.c).

Se precisa crescer é só fazer um `realloc()` atualizando o tamanho com a parte que calcula os espaço para os elementos do *array*.

Se isto não for possível por usar um compilador não conforme então para este caso a solução de usar só um *array* pode ser uma boa deixando a posição 0 reservada para o tamanho. Não é perfeita, mas deve funcionar bem em quase qualquer caso real, só precisa ter algum cuidado.

A ideia de índices auxiliares parece bem ruim e até pior que a fragmentação.